# Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'NavComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've a custom component (nav) inside.

When I use it , webpack compilation ends successfully but chrome throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'NavComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Here is my AppModule:

>

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, NavComponent],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `NavComponent` is a `@Component` or a `@Directive`, you need to add it into the `declarations`, instead of `imports`

```
...
declarations: [ AppComponent, NavComponent ],
...
```

Comment: I changed that, but I have this problem now .

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-nav' is not a known element:

Comment: @MedYassineMessaoud depends where you have used it

Comment: i used it in another component like in the angular , but i don't understand the problem